# What is the limit of simultaneous connections in one channel?

Tags: javascript, broadcast, agora.io

I want to know, what is the limit of simultaneous connections in one channel at the single point of time?

As far as I know the limit is four person.

Comment: If I go to the agora.io website and hover over the `dev center` hyperlink, the first ad I get is: `Supports voice calls, video chats and live interactive broadcasting. Scale from 1 to 1 million users per channel`. So it's very likely that you can find the answer in the reference manual of the specific product.

Comment: To go along with @Shilly, there's also a Pricing menu item, so I expect how many connections you get depends on how much you pay.

Comment: The amount you pay does not have any impact on the upper limit of users. The limitations are from the SDK and physical device. Please see my response below and disregard both of the above comments

Answer (score 1):

Within the Agora platform the limitations really depend on the number of active broadcasters.

If you have a single Broadcaster the channel can support up to 1m active viewers (audience). If you are using multiple broadcasters (live chat or broadcast with many hosts) the channels can support up to 17 active hosts streaming into a single channel.

Also as a physical hardware limitation, some mobile devices will struggle to keep up with the rendering on screen if you have too many active hosts, which is not a limitation of the SDK but the devices themselves.